# Update lat and long when the mapview camera is being moved?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview

Here's my code, that works but it doesn't get updated and it's not accurate. I simply want to apply the camera lat and lng to another variable.

```
let cameraLat = self.mapView.camera.centerCoordinate.latitude
let cameraLng = self.mapView.camera.centerCoordinate.longitude
```

Comment: which lat long you want here ?? you mean current location want to update here or any other location ??

Comment: No I mean when the user moves the map view with their finger I want the lat and long to update according to the camera. Also yes the current location of the mapview's camera.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### for google maps:

if you have set the `mapView.delegate = self` and you have implemented the `GMSMapViewDelegate` it's pretty easy to get the an event everytime the camera changes, so you mapView view changes.

you could either implement the `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didChangeCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition)` or `func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, idleAtCameraPosition position: GMSCameraPosition)` method.

and then access the new camera values (lat/lng) like you did before, so just reassign your variables to the new values.

### or MapKit:

add delegate to class like

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        mapView.delegate = self
    }
}
```

> This method is called whenever the currently displayed map region changes. During scrolling, this method may be called many times to report updates to the map position. Therefore, your implementation of this method should be as lightweight as possible to avoid affecting scrolling performance.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, regionDidChangeAnimated animated: Bool) {
   let lat = mapView.camera.centerCoordinate.latitude
   let lng = mapView.camera.centerCoordinate.longitude
}
```

Comment: Ah I was looking for that mapkit function but couldn't find it, thank you so much:)

Comment: can you accept it as the correct answer then please? :)

Comment: Also it's not updating the lat and lng for some reason, I thought It was working.

Comment: can you then show some more code? is you class subscribing to the `MKMapViewDelegate` like `class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate { }` ?

Comment: Hey, I totally forgot to do mapView.delegate = self, it's working just fine now. Thanks so mcuh!